# Member Activation Redirect conflicts with Twomile Login Redirect

Tags: add-on, members, login, extension

The add-ons Member Activation Redirect and Twomile Login Redirect don't play nicely together - has anyone gotten that to work?

It seems like the "welcome" page set under the first extension gets hijacked by the "last page" set with Login Redirect. I've tried setting Activation Redirect to have a lower priority (4) in exp_extensions, but that didn't help.

Some background from somebody who had the same problem: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/member-activation-redirect/viewthread/6897

Ideas? Thx!

Comment: Perhaps not useful, but you could take a look at [Freemember](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember) which can do both login and activation redirects natively.

Comment: I would going to suggest the same thing, except with Safecracker Registration + Authenticate. http://objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration A large number of support requests involve Twomile Login Redirect. When using my add-ons, uninstalling it fixes the problem. Again, not an answer to your question, but it is a solution to your problem.

Comment: Perhaps it's the lack of coffee in my bloodstream today, but I don't see that either of those add-ons has the ability to hijack to a "welcome" page when a new user clicks the authentication url in an email.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend not to use Twomile Login Redirect, we've encountered issues with it in the past, not a very good add-on.